# Update Woocommerce Product Image Link in Relation to Product SKU using REST API

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a website selling books on woo commerce and one of our suppliers supplying books images, and example link format for our images is: https://suppliername.com/index.aspx?sku=(SKU).lc.jpg&type=image

Is there a way to fetch the SKU of a product and update the (SKU) part of the link for each individual product using REST API?

Comment: Sure, this is possible! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well nothing as of yet, I've just been reading the documentation for the API as I've never used it before.